# cal/ncal show three months, starting on Mondays, one week per row

Tags: command-line, 17.10, calendar

In Debian I can run `ncal -3M -C` to get:

```
                            2017
      October               November              December        
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su  Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su  Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su  
                   1         1  2  3  4  5               1  2  3  
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8   6  7  8  9 10 11 12   4  5  6  7  8  9 10  
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15  13 14 15 16 17 18 19  11 12 13 14 15 16 17  
16 17 18 19 20 21 22  20 21 22 23 24 25 26  18 19 20 21 22 23 24  
23 24 25 26 27 28 29  27 28 29 30           25 26 27 28 29 30 31  
30 31
```

The following work:

- `cal -3`, does not start weeks on Mondays,
- `ncal -3M`, displays weeks as columns instead of rows,
- `ncal -C -3`, does not start weeks on Mondays.

But the following doesn't work: **`ncal -C -3M`**.

It seems that `-C` is mutually exclusive with `-M` on Ubuntu – `-M` not being a "general option" – both according to the manual and the *Usage* text displayed when attempting this. It's only a valid option to `ncal` as long as `-C` is not specified.

**Is it possible to make cal/ncal show three months, starting on Mondays, one week per row?**

Comment: fyi: it doesn't work on debian 9 (Stretch) or later; it only works on old-stable debian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ ncal -M -b -3
                            2017
      October               November              December        
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su  Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su  Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su  
                   1         1  2  3  4  5               1  2  3  
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8   6  7  8  9 10 11 12   4  5  6  7  8  9 10  
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15  13 14 15 16 17 18 19  11 12 13 14 15 16 17  
16 17 18 19 20 21 22  20 21 22 23 24 25 26  18 19 20 21 22 23 24  
23 24 25 26 27 28 29  27 28 29 30           25 26 27 28 29 30 31  
30 31
```

From the `man`:

```
-b      Use oldstyle format for ncal output.
```